# C# Resize Image at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to resize an image if size is over 1024x768 and after that save the new instance instead of the original one but this code is saving the original. how can I fix that?

```
      private static void ResizeImage(int newWidth, int newHeight, Stream OriginalImage, string targetPath)
    {
        using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(OriginalImage))
        {
            var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
            thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
            thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. How are we supposed to copy it run it ourselves of modify it? Post the code as text, formatted as code, exactly as explained in the Help Center.

Comment: I did that. It is my first time to post. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming "thumbnailImg" is supposed to be downscaled version of "image".

If so - use [Bitmap constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-bitmap-ctor(system-drawing-image-system-int32-system-int32)) designed exactly for this purpose:

```
Bitmap(Image, Int32, Int32)
```

For example:

```
var thumbnail = new Bitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight);
```